# CameraX VideoCapture use case. Access underlying AudioRecord object to display voice visualization

Tags: android, video, android-camerax

I need to display input audio level graph for pending video recording. I am using CameraX SDK and VideoCapture use case. Is it possible to access such a low level API for video recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, at least I didn't find any options to do it

I have same problem as u, to resolve it I use camera2 and MediaRecorder
U can use `MediaRecorder.maxAmplitude` to get info about "volume"

[Also u can try this](https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/RSU5iJEme5M), but anyway u need to use MediaRecorder
There is also spoken about reflection, but I didn't got how to get volume in that way

If u find how to do it with cameraX, please comment me

Answer (score 0):

When you start recording in camerax 1.3.0 you can receive different events. One of them is `VideoRecordEvent.Status` where it contains audioamplitude

```js
val pendingRecording = recorder.prepareRecording(activity, options).withAudioEnabled()

pendingRecording.start(cameraExecutor) { event ->
  when (event) {
     is VideoRecordEvent.Status -> {
      event.recordingStats.audioStats.audioAmplitude
     }
  }
}
```